# JQuery AJAX not executing in addon for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, firefox

I'm developping an addon for Mozilla Firefox. In the main.js file I call another script (script.js). Everything is working fine and script.js executes without any problems.
Now the next step is to retrieve data from an url using jquery ajax or json. As soon as I add code to do this, script.js is no longer executed. I cannot find any error messages, the script itself just does not execute.

I've tried different methods to retrieve the data:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {<<some code here>>});
$.get(url,function(data){<<some code here>>});
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    success: function(data){<<some code here>>})
});
```

I even tried using `var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;` instead of Ajax.

A friend of mine is working on the server side. If I enter the url in a browser, I get the correct answer, so this is not the problem. We've tried returning `JSON`, `JSONP` or pain text but script.js does not execute when adding code to retrieve data.

The addon is not a new idea, it is a Mozilla Firefox version of an extension that already runs in Chrome. There was no problem there to retrieve the data.

edit: 
So some more information, this is the code I'm using to retrieve the data:

```
alert("getting json");
/*$.getJSON(apiURL, function (data) {
    alert("data: " + data);
if (data != "-1") {
    $("#cur_li_" + country).click(function () {
        window.location = data.url;
    return true;
    }).css('cursor', 'pointer'); ;
    results = true;
} else {
    $("#cur_li_" + country).remove();
}
return true;
});*/
```

If I run this, it gives me the alert. As soon as I uncomment the code, the alert is no longer shown. If I enter the URL in the browser this is the reply:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Apr 2014 09:18:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 111

{"land":"de","prijs":"EUR 49.00"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We need to see the actual script that you're having problems with.

Comment: Can you post the response that you get through the browser? It might not be JSON, thus jquery will fail to process the response - and without a `.fail` on the request's promise object (that is returned by `$.ajax` and the likes), it will not tell you.

Comment: I've added the requested information. Thanks!